# How to initialize a variable when IBOutlet is initialized?

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet, initializer

It happened for me to write following code snippet in one of my `UIViewControllers` in my new iOS  Swift Application.

```
var starButtonsCount = starButtons.count
@IBOutlet var starButtons: [UIButton]!
```

Then straight next to the `starButtonsCount` variable declaration following error appeared in red.

> Error: Cannot use instance member ‘starButtons’ within property
>   initializer; property initializers run before ‘self’ is available.

So I found out that by declaring the `starButtonCount` variable as `lazy` we can resolve this error (temporary in the long run of the iOS App development process).

I'm curious to find out what are the other methods to solve this?

Is there a way to trigger the initialization for `starButtonCount` when the `starButtons` IBOutlets get initialized?

Comment: It is the purpose of `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: I thought so while I was searching on the Internet. But couldn't find a specific answer right to the point! Could you elaborate further in an answer?

Comment: What is the purpose not to declare a constant? The buttons are connected at design/compile time so you are supposed to know the number of buttons.

Comment: @vadian even though I had declared the `starButtonsCount` as a constant, still the same error appears. So the focus should be how the `BOutlets` get initialized and how to catch that and initialize my variable.

Comment: The same error cannot occur if `starButtonsCount` is declared as `let` with a constant `Int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is a method called when every object in a .xib have been deserialized and the graph of all outlets connected. Documentation says:

> **Declaration**
>
> `func awakeFromNib()`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after
>   all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When
>   an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have
>   all its outlet and action connections already established.The nib-loading infrastructure sends an `awakeFromNib`
>
> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they require. Although the default implementation of this method does nothing, many `UIKit` classes provide non-empty implementations. You may call the super implementation at any point during your own `awakeFromNib` method.

As in:

```
class MyUIViewController : UIViewController {
    var starButtonsCount = 0
    @IBOutlet var starButtons: [UIButton]!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        starButtonsCount = startButtons.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, It would be nicer if you could provide the answer with a code example too! :-)

Comment: @RandikaVishman this code can be set in `viewDidLoad` also so there is no new thing to learn here

Comment: @sh_Khan I think that's bit incorrect since more than `viewDidLoad` method, `awakeFromNib` deals directly with connections and initialization made related to the given `Nib` file (or the `StoryBoard` in this case). Please read this answer's document excerpt!

Comment: @Sh_Khan Of course there is many places where to put such a code, but OP exactly wanted to know how to capture the fact that outlets have been correctly set, and that is exactly the purpose of `awakeFromNib`, `viewDidLoad` is another thing.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
var starButtonsCount:Int! 
@IBOutlet var starButtons: [UIButton]! { 
    didSet { 
         starButtonsCount = starButtons.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well in that case, but this doesn't let you control multiple/complex settings of IBOutlets...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès don't get what you mean by multiple complex IBS , but handling in awakeFromNib has same effect as viewDidLoad ? the op is asking for a new way on the fly instead of the usual way

Comment: Personally I don't like the `propertyObserver` way since it lengthens the number of code lines within a particular `UIViewController` class and it can be not that much readable too!

Comment: @Sh_Khan Basically you can't control order of outlet initializations, then in case of complex dependancies it is not manageable with didSet

Comment: And why i care with that if eventually the var will be set correctly plus will get an easy observer

Comment: @Sh_Khan I did not mean that your answer is wrong, just that it can be problematic in more general case. A better answer would have then been to implement it as a `get` to have the right value every time...

Comment: can be `problematic` how ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan If a value depend on another, order is not guaranteed!

Answer (score 2):

Also note there is no need for `starButtonsCount` to be a stored variable:

```
var starButtonsCount: Int {
   return starButtons.count
}
```

In this case it would be probably better to use `starButtons.count` directly since the variable does not improve the code in no way.

In a general case, there is no need to store derived state unless storing it provides some performance boost (e.g. caching calculations).

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is a constant

```
let starButtonsCount = 8 // or whatever the number of buttons is
```

`IBOutlets` are connected at build time so the number of buttons won't change at runtime.

You could add an assert line in `viewDidLoad` to get informed if the number of buttons changed in a future version of the app

```
assert(starButtons.count == starButtonsCount, "number of buttons has changed, adjust starButtonsCount")
```

Comment: Sorry, the information was insufficient for you it seems! Actually the number of buttons may change over the time if I decide to add more buttons.

Comment: Also, by adding an `assert` line, isn't it make the program more complex even though it might secure the app from the options to fail? (thinking)

Comment: In this case you get a fatal error in the `assert` line to change the constant value.

Comment: But thanks for the effort! This is also a simplification for some programs.

Comment: `Asserts` are only considered in `debug` scheme. Any runtime check or calculation of a value which will never change is unnecessary.